# Not downloading files to NSDocumentsDirectory correctly?

Tags: ios, swift, download, nsurlconnection, nsurl

I want to download files to my NSDocumentsDirectory. I grab a url that is a download link and that url is stored into a variable called `url` Here is my code to perform the download and store it into the `Documents Directory` so:

```
let data = NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(urlRequest, returningResponse: &response,error: &error)

if data != nil && error == nil{ 
  var documentsDirectoryUrl =  NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask).first as! NSURL
  documentsDirectoryUrl = documentsDirectoryUrl.URLByAppendingPathComponent(url.lastPathComponent)
  //Hold this file as an NSData and write it to the new location
  let fileData = NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string:url)!)

  fileData!.writeToURL(documentsDirectoryUrl, atomically: false)   // true
  println("\(data!.length) bytes of data was written to Documents Directory.")
}
else if data!.length == 0 && error == nil{
  println("No data was returned")
}
else if error != nil{
  println("Error happened = \(error)");
}
```

Since the files I'm downloading are music files, when I try to play audio from these music files, I get an error when I try to access the file's path because that file's path is set to nil. I think it's an issue with downloading the file because I had the code working before but then I changed how I downloaded the music files and the code seemed to break. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Do you check the simulator sandbox and if there is download files in it?

Comment: No I didn't. How do you do that?

Comment: Your code makes no sense you checked if data != nil then you loaded fileData from url ??? BTW url is a string ?

Comment: @LeonardoSavioDabus I just grabbed the code from this link: https://github.com/vandadnp/iOS-8-Swift-Programming-Cookbook/blob/master/chapter-networking/Downloading%20Synchronously%20with%20NSURLConnection/Downloading%20Synchronously%20with%20NSURLConnection/ViewController.swift and modified it so that it would download into the Documents Directory.

Comment: Log `documentsDirectoryUrl`, then double click finder->go to folder->paste the url then go there to check.

Comment: @user1871869 try using mine as reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import UIKit


let documentsDirectoryUrl =  NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask).first as! NSURL

var error:NSError?
var response:NSURLResponse?

let data = NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xs4RX.jpg")!), returningResponse: &response, error: &error)

if let data = data where error == nil {
    let destinationUrl = documentsDirectoryUrl.URLByAppendingPathComponent(response!.suggestedFilename!)
    data.writeToURL(destinationUrl, atomically: true)   // true
    println("\(data.length) bytes of data was written to Documents Directory.")

}
if let error = error {
    println(error.description)
}
```

Comment: I'm just a little confused: What might have been wrong with my previous implementation?

Comment: @user1871869 You are welcome. there were many errors there as I commented. Try to compare both codes and you will notice the difference